# How do i fetch the click date in home away calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

```
$('.calendar').calendar({
    'fetch': false,
    'numberOfMonths': [1,6], 
    'clicked': {
        'reserve': function(element, reservation) {
            alert(reservation.guestFirstName);
            console.log(reservation.guestFirstName);
        },
    },
    'defaultDate': '". $defaultDate ."'
  });
```

Above is my initialization code.It is working for reserveation dates but i want to fetch any date clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).text())
    });
});
```